# Need help identifying the indentation error in a code block

Tags: python

I tried defining a function below (part of a longer code block), but came across an 'indentation error' identified at the 4th line.
Could somebody please tell me what the error is?

```
guess = int(raw_input('Your first guess?  '))
def next_guess(n):
    n -= 1
    print "You now have %s attempts left" %n
    guess = int(raw_input('Your next guess?  '))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Your indentation is a mix of tabs and spaces. The tab character might look like it's four spaces wide in your text editor/IDE, but Python [can interpret it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) as anywhere between one and eight spaces. This can cause Python to become very confused. Replace the tab on your `n -= 1` line with spaces.